# Manually delay audio in chrome or system-wide (Mac OSX)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, audio, bluetooth, delay

I got new Bluetooth speakers and inherently they seem to have a delay of about 0.5 to 1s when watching streams or videos online. I already mailed to the manufacturer and I was told that this has to do with how they make use of the Bluetooth protocol (pair of speakers in master-slave mode for stero sound) and how the respective video player is doing encoding/decoding. iTunes for instance seems to be just fine while vlc and all streams in browsers have this delay.

So I was wondering whether there is a way to manually delay audio either just in the browser (chrome) or even system-wide on MacOSX?! It would be great if the possible solution was transient since I do not want the delay when I am not using these speakers.

Additionally it would be just perfect if somebody even knew how to this on iOS although I don't think that it is possible there, that's why I did not include iOS in the title.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that the same issue still persist in macOS Sierra. There are no problems with Safari or iTunes, but some third-party apps -- including Google Chrome -- have this issue. I think that native apps compensate with the delay while some 3rd party devs don't. I think that's partly due to the Chrome devs, but a workaround would be nice until this feature is added to/this is fixed in newer versions of Chrome.